# AngularJS - use variable declared in a promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to call service within a function and then to use response data from the service, using `.then`, but I'm not able to return anything from that function

```
 var status;

 var getStatus = function(data,$scope){

            registrationService.registration(data,$scope)
            .then(function (response) {

                return status = response.status;

                console.log("Status1: " + status);
            });     

}


status = getStatus(data,$scope);
console.log("Status2: " + status);
```

when I move service call outside function all works fine

```
        registrationService.registration(data,$scope)
        .then(function (response) {

            status = response.status;

            console.log("Status1: " + status);
        });
```

but in this case I'm not able to access `status` variable outside callback which I need to reuse to  check statuses.

Comment: @baao `return` of what? I have already `return status = response.status` there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. One, assignments return `undefined`.

So,

```
return status = response.status;
```

Is returning undefined.

Two, a return statment will stop the execution of a function block.

This call below is not console.logging, because that return prevents it from reaching the console.log.

```
registrationService.registration(data,$scope)
            .then(function (response) {

                return status = response.status;

                console.log("Status1: " + status);
            });
```

This call is (that you say is working, which I assume means you're getting that console.log) is working NOT because you pulled it out of the function, but because you removed the return statement.

```
registrationService.registration(data,$scope)
        .then(function (response) {

            status = response.status;

            console.log("Status1: " + status);
        });
```

Update with more detail:

`getStatus` returns nothing so it returns undefined. Which means status is getting set to undefined right before your final console log.

```
status = getStatus(data,$scope);
```

If `registrationService.registration(data,$scope)` is async then you're going to have to wait until it resolves before console.logging. Currently you console.log synchronously right after you execute `getStatus`

**Update 2**

```
var status;

 var getStatus = function(data,$scope){

    return registrationService.registration(data,$scope)
            .then(function (response) {

                status = response.status;

                console.log("Status1: " + status);
            });     

}


getStatus(data,$scope)
    .then(function () {
        console.log("Status2: " + status);
    })
```

**Update 3**

For the follow up question in the comments below, you should really refactor it like this:

```
function getStatus (data,$scope){

    return registrationService.registration(data,$scope)
            .then(function (response) {

                if (response.status === "pending") {
                    return getStatus(data, $scope)
                } else if (response.status === "accepted") {
                    // return something else
                } else {
                    // return something else 
                }
                console.log("Status1: " + status);
            });     

}
getStatus(data, $scope)
    .then(function (data) {
        // do whatever you want
    });
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my issue which is why I'm not able to see value of a `status` variable when functions was used. When `Status2` is `undefinied`  not `Status1`

Comment: "is async then you're going to have to wait until it resolves" - how do I know when got resolved then?

Comment: You need to chain another .then block off of it, and console.log inside the .then

Comment: so without `.then` there is no way to do that? Can you give me an example chained `.then` blocks?

Comment: check update 2, that should do it. Note that you have to return the promise out of ```getStatus``` just like @baao was saying. Then you can chain more .then's off of the ```getStatus``` call.

Comment: OK, now it works. Further question is how can I loop based on returned status value? There are 3 statements - pending, success, declined. When Is "pending" I need to execute `getStatus` once again to see if ended up with 'success' or 'declined'

Comment: Update 3, will call getStatus again if you get a pending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154560/discussion-between-jlogan-and-jacktheknife).